# How show 4 images on slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im using that slider: https://www.codeply.com/go/s3I9ivCBYH

I need to add one more image to that slider, to show 4 images.

Im already change html to:

```
<div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
```

to

```
<div class="carousel-item col-md-3">
```

Now he has space to show 4, but does not show the 4th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the number of visible items per slide to 4 and set up your columns accordingly. But what seems to have done the trick is tweaking the css. I got it to work check it out:

https://www.codeply.com/go/tRCLIBR462